# Custom Comparator for sorting string based on frequency of each character

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparator

I made a custom comparator for sorting a string based on the frequency of characters in it.

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Character> {
    HashMap<Character,Integer> map;
    public CustomComparator(String s) {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        for(char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            map.put(ch,map.getOrDefault(ch,0)+1);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Character ch1,Character ch2) {
        return map.get(ch2) - map.get(ch1);
    }
}

Arrays.sort(array,new CustomComparator(s));
```

Assume array is an Character array, is the hashmap filled everytime a comparison between two chars are made, or it is filled once and then order is decided based on filled map's frequencies?

Comment: This is basic Java. The hashmap is populated in the constructor. How many times is the constructor invoked? Hint: count the number of occurrences of the 'new' keyword.

Comment: So, the once-at-the-invoke map is used for all comparisons? I could not get the hint.

Comment: I think @Manulako's answer explains it well. Happens once, same as the number of 'new's.

Comment: @Michael Got it , thanks!

Comment: By the way, the `char` type and its `Character` wrapper class have been [legacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) since Java 2. As a 16-bit value `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. To work with individual characters, use [code point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating the comparator and passing it as a parameter to the `Arrays.sort` method, that means that there will only be one instance and therefore the `HashMap` is filled once.

It's the same as if it were written like this:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Character> {
    //... same as yours
}

CustomComparator cs = new CustomComparator(s);
Arrays.sort(array, cs);
```

The comparator is instantiated once and since the map is filled in the constructor, it will be filled once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sire.

Comment: But, do you think it will sort the string based on frequency of chars? Actually it fails. How can we correct it?